# Cannot install packages in Mint: "Unable to fetch some archives"

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, apt

I'm running Linux Mint 16 (Petra). I was able to install packages normally until, at least, april 18th (two weeks ago). Since yesterday I cannot install packages anymore. For example, if I try to install `screen`:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  screen
Install these packages without verification [y/N]?
```

If I ignore the warning, I get

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main screen amd64 4.0.3-14ubuntu10
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/screen/screen_4.0.3-14ubuntu10_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.getdeb.net_ubuntu_dists_trusty-getdeb_apps_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.getdeb.net_ubuntu_dists_trusty-getdeb_apps_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

With other packages it's the same. First the warning, then some 404s, then the "unable to fetch some archives" error.

I've tried running `apt-get update` (which also throws lots of 404s), checked that I'm not behind a proxy, nothing worked.

From what I've read I guess it may have something to do with my distro being unsupported. But Petra when obsolete in July 2014 and I've had this problem since only a few days ago. If that's the problem, do I need to upgrade or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Petra is based on Ubuntu 13.10, Saucy Salamander. The Saucy files were kept around on http://archive.ubuntu.com until a few days ago; they are now available on http://old-releases.ubuntu.com. If you really want to continue using Petra, you should replace "archive" with "old-releases" in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` configuration file.

There hasn't been any security support for this release for quite a while, so you should really upgrade to a newer version of Mint...

Comment: Fine. But my `sources.list` file says `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main universe` (note `lucid`, not `saucy`). Is that normal?

Comment: There's presumably another file somewhere in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with the `saucy` lines...